# VMAccessForLinux fails to provision on Azure RM VM

Tags: linux, azure, ssh

I've tried absolutely everything I can think of to do a SSH reset of my user on my Linux VM (Hortonworks Sandbox to be precise).

The VMAccessForLinux will not install, it simply states that it fails to provision:

[image]

I've tried adding it as 1.*,1.1, 1.2 and now 1.4 as per https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-ssh-connections.md

I can't access my SSH, and I can't do any of the Azure reset commands, either using Azure CLI or Azure PS.

The VM is a RM vm.

How can I resolve this? 
In PS I get errors like:

[image]

I'm beyond tearing my hair out. 
And before anyone suggest that I use the portal, this is what I'm offered there (thanks Azure):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say if this is a universal fix, but I managed to resolve this issue, by using the following in the Azure CLI:

```
$ azure vm reset-access -n {VMNAME} -g {GROUPNAME} \
    -u {SSH_USER} -p {SSH_PASS} -E 1.4 -vv --json
```

It did NOT work for my original user on the box though; I created ANOTHER user, and from there I did a password reset with a `sudo` on the box, then I could SSH into the box from that user.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, can you go through the instructions here if you've not already. The VM extension has changed recently and that is the latest doc to go through: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-vmaccess-extension-to-reset-login-credentials-for-linux-vm/.

#### EDIT #1

Glad to see you resolved it by creating a new user with reset-access. 
If `azure vm reset-access` should fail, the next step would have been to download this tool which can allow you to inspect the VHD when not logged onto the VM: https://github.com/paulmey/inspect-azure-vhd - and inspect Waagent log is `/var/log/waagent.log` (You can see extension updates here) and
`extension.log` in `/var/log/azure/`.

Comment: It is happening in East US.

I performed all the steps in the link you've associated; I've attempted those changes in both Azure CLI (in ARM mode) and PowerShell.